# Leaflet sometimes shows World Maps when it is set to current location

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, world-map

I have setup a map to the current location as shown below.

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid', {doubleClickZoom: false}).locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 22});
```

But sometimes the map does not load to current location. It shows a map of the world. For example:

[image: Image showing World Map than showing me current lcoation]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

This happens if the user blocks the browser from accessing his/her location. Set a default center so that users who block location access do not see the world view. For example:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
    minZoom: 9,
    maxZoom: 18,
    zoom: 12,
    center: [40.423494,-3.682068],
    doubleClickZoom: false,
}).locate({setView: true});
```

See my Codepen for an example: https://codepen.io/amapolauditiva/pen/XWmdMaw

Comment: But with this change the location always sets to default to Madrid Locaton or my current location ?

Comment: Replace the coordinates with the default location that you want to use for your map.